Powershell performance: variable expansion vs -f operator
I have some code that takes a lot of strings from XML and expands the variables in those strings. And it is god awful slow. If I only get into the range of a thousand repetitions processing can take minutes, which is just pathetic.
Now I am wondering if PowerShell's variable expansion in double quoted strings is just VERY under optimized, and maybe the format operator would be better. So I tried this as a proof of concept
$string1 = 'C:\MyFile.txt'
$string2 = 'folder1'

(Measure-Command {
    foreach ($i in 1...10000) {
        $temp = "C:\Folder\subfolder\$string1\$string2"
    }
}).TotalMilliseconds

(Measure-Command {
    foreach ($i in 1...10000) {
        $temp = 'C:\Folder\subfolder\{0}\{1}' -f $string1, $string2
    }
}).TotalMilliseconds

There is a difference, at least most if the time, but it isn't dramatic nor is it always the format operator that wins (90% of the time?). BUT, this is a pretty artificial test, and I wonder if it is a known issue, where string expansion in an environment where there may be 50 or 100 variables in scope is consistently and dramatically slower.
I did try adding a little code to artificially create some variables that aren't being expanded, like this...
foreach ($i in 1...1000) {
    Remove-Variable -Name:"var$i" -Force
    New-Variable -Name:"var$i" -Value: $i
}

But again, not a major difference and also still pretty artificial.
Finally, I tested that code, sans the Remove-Variable, running in the console rather than the ISE, since I have seen those two environments be massively different as well. Still no major differences.
If the code to iterate over the double quoted string looking for variables to expand is not as efficient as the format operator looking for the much simpler index tokens, but I can't see that in these rather artificial tests, it would be a bummer.
But if I just have to accept that PowerShell is slow, well I guess that's what I have to do. I have had to do that before, speed is not something PowerShell has ever been about.
But if someone can point me to an indication that this effort is worth it I would love to get this code into the realm of a few seconds to process rather than minutes, even if out takes me a few days to do the refactor.

What is the actual question? In my opinion string manipulation is always expensive independent of the language. (As an aside, you could also consider using -Join here: 'C:\Folder\subfolder', $string1, $string2 -Join '\'). What I mean is that I don't think you can improve the performance of what you show here but there could be a performance improvement if you take your issue a whole.

My general view: the performance of a complete (PowerShell) solution is supposed to be better than the sum of its parts. So what is behind "have some code that takes a lot of strings from XML and expands the variables in those strings"?

Can you provide a concrete code sample that demonstrates the performance levels you’re seeing when doing variable expansion? If the code needs a specific runtime context (e.g. a specific xml document template, lots of variables in scope, a loop to iterate, etc) can you add code to initialise that as well. It’s going to be difficult to comment on performance without having code to run locally…

@mclayton unfortunately I can't really provide an example that isn't the whole program. The time it would take to do it would be more than the time to just refactor and see if it makes a difference. So, lacking some known performance issue like the pipeline, I guess I decide if I will just do the refactor as an exercise, and hope it addresses performance as well as teaches me something.

@iron I have put a timer on the code that does the expansion, separate from the XML, and it is definitely there that the lion's share of the time is burned. I realize I really have three conditions, the string from the XML can be a literal, nothing but a variable,  or a string with a variable also. And right now I am forcing an expand on everything. So I think it would be a good exercise for me to refactor to deal with each situation separately and see if that optimizers things.

And power goes out momentarily and for the next 6 hours. So, no internet and no questions answered. I guess a refactor is a good way to use that "down" time.

By the way, in all your foreach ($i in 1...1000) your range expressions actually have 3 dots - e.g. 1 dot dot dot 1000 - the third dot is being parsed as a decimal point so it's equivalent to 1 .. 0.1000 which expands to the sequence @(1, 0) - you're only iterating the loops 2 times, not 1000. You can see this with foreach ($i in 1...1000) {} }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].Condition.PipelineElements[0].Expression - the Right property is .1000 (with a decimal point), not 1000

@Gordon Can you post a snippet of the code that does the expansion? If you've already diagnosed the approximate call sites at which the slowdown occurs then that's obviously a good place to start :)

There is no performance difference between these 2, your performance tests are flawed and that's about it

@santiago-squarzon well, that sounds like my performance tests are good, since they seem to indicate there isn't really any performance difference.
